# How to set value in a sap.m.Datepicker in a row same as in above row?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, sapui5

I have a table in which one of the Column has sap.m.Datepicker element. There is a checkbox which says "same start date for all" and a plus button to add a row. So when plus button is clicked i am pushing a empty row in the table model, but if check box is ticked then start date should be same in the new row as in previous row. 
But if i am unchecking the checkbox, still start date in a new row is setting the same.
See the code below:

```
var datepickered =  new sap.m.DatePicker({
        value: {
            path:"{Start_Date}",
            type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
                pattern:"MMM dd yy",
                source:{pattern:"MM/dd/yy"}
            })
        },});
```

Now i am setting the date in new row.

```
var modelData = sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableid").getModel().getData();
var value = sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableid").getItems()[0].getCells()[3];
modelData.push({Start_Date:value.getValue()});
sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableid").setModel(modelData);
```

[sanpshot of the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaaSX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableid").getModel().refresh(true)` to refresh the model manually and apply the changes made on the underlying data object. 
It's unnecessary to use the `sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableid").setModel(modelData)` code, because the model itself is already assigned to the table.

Also make sure that `sap.ui.getCore().byId("tableid").getModel().getData()` returns an array, not an object with a property which points to the desired array. It depends on your JSON data model.

**Edit:**
According to the attached JSBin source code, I found the following issues:

```
var datepickerst =  new sap.m.DatePicker({
    value: {
        path:"{Start_Date}",
        type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
            pattern:"MMM dd yy",
            source:{pattern:"MM/dd/yy"}
        })
    }
});
```

You should align the `pattern` and `source` properties to support the same format (because you are using `getValue()`, which will return the date in `MMM dd yy` format, but the `DatePicker` itself waits for a date in format `MM/dd/yy`.

The other thing is that `path` property should not contain the curly braces. Based on these things, a correct `DatePicker` definition should look like this:

```
var datepickerst =  new sap.m.DatePicker({
    value: {
        path:"Start_Date",
        type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
            pattern:"MMM dd yy",
            source:{pattern:"MMM dd yy"}
        })
    }
});
```

Also make sure that you align pattern in the initialization phase of your code to the correct source format.

Comment: hi nistv4n, I tried your advice but still its coming the same date in new row even when checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @AshishJain Could you post the relevant code for a smart check (you can use JSBin or something else)?

Comment: I am sharing a link for JSBin [link](https://jsbin.com/fozima/edit?html,console,output) . In this JSBin if Checkbox is ticked and then a row is added than same date is not setting in the new row

Comment: @AshishJain I updated my answer with my recommendations.